# Browsers auto-correct img src – why?

Tags: javascript, src

I'm trying to load some images with JavaScript. Even if the image does not exist, somehow browsers try to correct the path. So if I have:

```js
var path = "somepath/myimage_10.jpg";
var my_image = new Image();
my_image.src = path;
some_div.appendChild(myimage);
```

...and `myimage_10.jpg` doesn't exist, the browser shows `myimage_1.jpg` instead! Can you please explain what is happening?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: We're going to need some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here...

Comment: What browsers have you tried that have done this? Do any messages show in the console? Have you tried it with any image numbers besides `10`?

Comment: It sounds like you're simply mistaken. The browser doesn't change strings on a whim. If you recently renamed the images, the browser might load the "wrong" image from its cache.

Comment: Possibly the webserver is doing a rewrite or redirect.